# OMNeT++ disassembling received messages

Tags: c++, omnet++

I want to read data from my received message in OMNeT++ and store it.

This is what my message format looks like:

```
packet ServerMsg
{
    String code;
    String text;
}
```

I know how to build and send it, but not how to disassemble it at the receiving point.

Now I want to store 'code' in 'a' and 'text' in 'b'.

```
void Server::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
   String a;
   String b;
}
```

What's the way to go here?

Comment: IMO, this is not `C`. Removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the incoming message to the appropriate type and then can access all the member variables of the message class:

```
#include "ServerMsg_m.h"
...    
void Server::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
   String a;
   String b;
   ServerMsg *pkt = check_and_cast<ServerMsg *>(msg);
   a = pkt->a;
   b = pkt->b;
}
```